# trying to grab a value from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typeerror

im trying to make it so it only shows specific sizes for the array i have, this is the array

```
const products = [{
    name: "14K bracelet",
    id: "1",
    description: "Beautfull 14K gold Bracelet",
    price: 100,
    size: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    
}
```

and this is how im trying to grab the values from it

```
                    <Dropdown.Item className="dropdown-item" href="#/action-1">{products.size[0]}</Dropdown.Item>
```

but im getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Comment: products is an array so since you are trying to access first result try `products[0].size....`

Comment: hmm now its saying TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')

Comment: [please close your brackets

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'products' as an array instead of object.

Arrays have elements(object - keys). For working with them you must use indexes(f.e. array[0] for getting the first element).

For more information:

Arrays: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Objects: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

```js
const products = [{
    name: "14K bracelet",
    id: "1",
    description: "Beautfull 14K gold Bracelet",
    price: 100,
    size: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    
}];

console.log(products[0].size[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
const products = {
    name: "14K bracelet",
    id: "1",
    description: "Beautfull 14K gold Bracelet",
    price: 100,
    size: [1, 2, 3, 4]    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get access to to an object in array so it should be like

```js
let product = [{name:'test', size:[1,2,3,4]}]

console.log(product[0].size[1])
```